# jQuery Click Event for Dynamically Created Links Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am displaying a list of users in a table. Then, I have a button to allow a user to view more details about a specific user. However, I am having a hard time getting the ID for the user that is clicked on. I am not sure why it's not working. What am I doing wrong? I tried several options, and none of them work.

**Partial code of how data the links are generated in my view.**

```
 if (Model != null) {
    if (Model.Count() > 0) {
         foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
        <td><div class="centerText">@item.UserID</div></td>
        <td><div class="centerText">@item.FirstName</div></td>
        <td><div class="centerText">@item.LastName</div></td>
        <td><div class="centerText"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default Detail" id="@item.UserID">Details</a></div></td>
        </tr>
      }
    }
}
```

**My jQuery function**

```
$(function () {
   $('.Detail').on('click', function (event) {
      var dt = $(this).attr('id');
       console.log('dt');
   });
```

});

**I also tried it this way:**

```
if (Model != null) {
    if (Model.Count() > 0) {
         foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
        <td><div class="centerText">@item.UserID</div></td>
        <td><div class="centerText">@item.FirstName</div></td>
        <td><div class="centerText">@item.LastName</div></td>
        <td><div class="centerText"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default Detail" onclick="test(@item.UserID)" data-id="@item.UserID">Details</a></div></td>
        </tr>
      }
    }
}
```

**Here is the Javascript function that I created. It kept giving**

```
function test(e){
  console.log(e);
};
```

**I get this error:**

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'test' is undefined
```

**updated on 11/21/15 @7:53 AM EST**

I removed the for loop and created a single cell with 1 click button. The click event is not registered. I tried it with 'on', 'live', and 'delegate' with no success.

```
<div class="table table-responsive" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><div class="centerText">Date Created</div></th>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"><div class="centerText"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default Detail">Detail</a></div></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
   </div>


@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.table tbody tr td div').delegate('.Detail','click', function ()       
        {
            console.log('you click me');
        });
     </script>
    }
```

Comment: try to `function test(e)` instead of `var function test(e)`.

Comment: You need to use `var dt = $(this).data('id');` - your adding a `data-` attribute to the link, not an` `id` attribute

Comment: I changed it to 'var dt = $(this).data('id');', but the click event is not being registered. When I click on the button, it did not show errors in the console window, but I did not see my expected result either.

Comment: Are you adding this links dynamically (i.e. after the initial page has been loaded? (in which case you need to use event delegation)

Comment: Re your last edit - you have the parameters the wrong way around - `$('.table').on('click', '.Detail', function() {`

Comment: I realize that so I fix it. The issue was mainly due a text area control. The moment that I remove it, it works as expected.

Comment: Then add your own answer and accept it to close it out so other don't waste their time adding answers.

Comment: I did add my answer, but I could not accept it until 2 days later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was causing the problem. I had a modal popup within the form. I was looking to add a textarea, so I added this code '

```
<textarea name="reasonForArchiveText" id="reasonForArchiveText" />
```

That's the code that was preventing me from getting the click event. As I was playing around with the code, I commented out the modal popup, and things started to work. Then, I commented section of the modal until I finally found the culprit. The minute that I commented it out, the code works.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the attribute `id` which doesn't exist. Use below to get `data-id`

```
$(function () {
   $('.Detail').on('click', function (event) {
      var dt = $(this).data('id'); 
       console.log(dt);
   });
```

you can also use

```
var dt = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

Second one (remove var):

```
function test(e){
  console.log(e);
};
```

Comment: I remove data from the attribute. I am still not getting anything. I commented out this section "var dt = $(this).data('id'); " and did a console.log('dt');' There was nothing in the console view. It did not register the click event. In addition, I remove the word 'var' that was appearing in from of the function name. It still gave me the function not define error.

Comment: Don't put dt in quotes in console.log. also try stepping through your code by putting break points. You will know what's going o ln

Answer (score 0):

> Partial code of how data the links are generated in my view. change id instead of data-id.

```
if (Model != null) {
if (Model.Count() > 0) {
     foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
    <td><div class="centerText">@item.UserID</div></td>
    <td><div class="centerText">@item.FirstName</div></td>
    <td><div class="centerText">@item.LastName</div></td>
    <td><div class="centerText"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default Detail" id="@item.UserID">Details</a></div></td>
    </tr>
  }
}
}
```

> My jQuery function

```
$(function () {
   $('.Detail').on('click', function (event) {
     var dt = $(this).attr('id');
   console.log('dt');
   });

});
```

> I also tried it this way:

```
if (Model != null) {
if (Model.Count() > 0) {
     foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
    <td><div class="centerText">@item.UserID</div></td>
    <td><div class="centerText">@item.FirstName</div></td>
    <td><div class="centerText">@item.LastName</div></td>
    <td><div class="centerText"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default Detail" onclick="test(@item.EncounterID)" data-id="@item.UserID">Details</a></div></td>
    </tr>
  }
}
}
```

> Here is the Javascript function that I created. It kept giving. (Remove var before function).

```
function test(e){
  console.log(e);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/4zzkpqys/1/) is how I reproduced your problem with *JavaScript runtime error: 'test' is undefined*.

### Scenario

I guess that you've defined the function `test` probably in your jQuery DOM ready function `$(function(){...}`.

If so, the function `test` is undefined because by the time the DOM is loading, AND the event handlers on DOM elements are being registered (in your case the `onclick` in the link), the function `test` is *not yet known to the document*, and therefore undefined.

### Solution

Try to move your `test` function's declaration outside of jQuery's DOM ready function. That is,

```
$(function(){
   //code that has to run once the DOM is ready
}); 

function test(e){
   console.log(e);
}
```

[***DEMO***](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/4zzkpqys/2/)